# How to apply font awesome icon color - including white shades not just the outlines

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

How do I color the font awesome icon, especially the ones with white shade

For example I added the below css style to font awesome icon "fa fa-files-o", but that doesn't color the whole icon, only the outlines are showing in green.How can I ensure the whole icon has the colour?

```
.file-icon-green{
  color: #36931a;
  background-color: #3e935f;
}

<i class='fa fa-files-o file-icon-green'></i>
```

Comment: read the doc if font awesome

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan have already seen the link that you have posed here. My example is also similar to the one there but that doesnt work, hence this post.

Comment: Anyway is not font awesome 5

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome works like a normal font does.

For example: if you tried to style a "O", only the circular part of it is coloured, and the "hole" remains whatever the background colour is.

I don't think there is a method for achieving what you want with FontAwesome, you would need to utilise a graphic instead.